# In React: Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-lodable'?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-loadable

I am new to react.
I am getting an error **( Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-lodable' )** while doing routing in my react app.

Here is my code:

**route.js:**

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Loadable from 'react-loadable';
import './App.css';

const Loading = () => <div> Loading... </div>;

const Home=Loadable({
    loader:()=>import('./components/home-component/Home'),
    loading:Loading
});

const User=Loadable({
    loader:()=>import('./components/user-component/User'),
    loading:Loading

});

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
      <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component="Home" />
          <Route path="/user" component="User" />
      </Switch>
  </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Have you installed `react-loadable` with `npm i` or `yarn add`?

Comment: react-loadable@5.4.0  is installed.

Comment: @ShubhamVerma npm start???

Comment: there is a typo in your import as per your error message, please check it out , error says you spelled `'react-loadable';` as ` react-lodable'`

Comment: Yes I have installed with npm install react-loadable --save

Answer (score 0):

As per your code you are doing it right but error says `Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-lodable'` so some where you are misspelling it as `react-lodable`
instead of `react-loadable`

Comment: I don't think so. I have used correct one from https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html

Comment: try adding you app to sandbox so that it will easy to help

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same issue, when I deleted my node modules and did
    `yarn install` or `npm install`
it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same issue too, I found that `react-loadable` did not exist in my `package.json`, then tried `npm install react-loadable`